# Will Dynamically Loaded Files With The Same Listener Script Load Twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-structures

Ok. This script works fine, but something tells me this is not a good coding practice. I have a HTML file that contains a script for adding a listener to the  in the div class .button-box. This same HTML file loads another HTML file (using .load js) that also has a .button-box div and a script to add a listener to it.

The listener script is just a switch that looks for a data element so there is no conflict (nor will there be) on the code. Basically the first one has 3 cases and the loaded one adds another 3 cases. But in my finished page I have duplicate $(".button-box").on('click', 'a' ...

Is this a coding no no? thoughts?

### Edit

```
$(".button-box").on('click', 'a' ,function() {
    switch(this.dataset.button_ref) {
                case "download_single_file":
                    alert("Beep Bop Blop Beep BEEP!... Your File is Downloading");
                    break;
                case "other cases":
                    other code to execute when button is pressed.
                    break:
    }
}
```

Above is the switch case code. So I have all my buttons in a .button-box class and as I load the page I pull in sub pages that also have buttons in a .button-box class.

Comment: yes, event listeners will get added again. Can use `off()` to first remove them before binding a new one

Comment: Will that remove all the options from my first switch too though?

Comment: not sure exactly what is meant by `switch` or what your code looks like

Comment: Please see the above edits. That is the code that would be in both the main page and the sub loaded pages

Comment: simplest solution is don't load the same code twice. It's redundant. Did you try using `off()` before `on()` like suggested?

Comment: well each loaded sub form adds to the switch case. So if I do off it will remove some of the cases

Comment: why would it? You would be binding the same event handler

Comment: Each html page that I am loading has additional buttons with additional functions. The only code that is the same is the actual listener "$(".button-box").on('click', 'a' ,function() {" So if I use off to remove the listener and then on when the new page is loaded wouldn't I lose the case for the first buttons that were loaded. Because the subsequent loaded divs do not contain the original cases nor should they since not all of them will be loaded every time. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: then that is basically a design flaw. Use more specific selectors or use attributes of elements to modify the handler logic

Comment: That was my question. So you are saying that could potentially create problems? Is there a way to extend the on click function code somehow without removing it and re adding an amended version?

Comment: please create a scenario demo. Adding some classes to your elements would likely resolve your problem.